# Shell: как склеить строки

Tags: unix, shell, строки

Хочу создавать файлы и присваивать им имена через скрипт, но вот проблема, надо имена присваивать разные. Как реализовать? Дело в том, что в скрипт в переменную передается параметр строковый, от которого и пляшется имя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sh-4.2$ x="AAA"
sh-4.2$ y="BBB"
sh-4.2$ z="$x$y"
sh-4.2$ echo $z
AAABBB
```